# parsing HTML with Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, dom, xul

```
uri = 'http://www.nytimes.com/';
searchuri = 'http://www.google.com/search?';
searchuri += 'q='+ encodeURIComponent(uri) +'&btnG=Search+Directory&hl=en&cat=gwd%2FTop';
req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open('GET', searchuri, true);
req.onreadystatechange = function (aEvt) {
    if (req.readyState == 4) {
        if(req.status == 200) {
            searchcontents = req.responseText;
            myHTML = searchcontents;
            var tempDiv = document.createElement('div');
            tempDiv.innerHTML = myHTML.replace(/<script(.|\s)*?\/script>/g, '');
            parsedHTML = tempDiv;
            sitefound = sc_sitefound(uri, parsedHTML);
        }
    }
};
req.send(null);

function sc_sitefound(uri, parsedHTML) {
    alert(parsedHTML);
    gclasses = parsedHTML.getElementsByClassName('g');
    for (var gclass in gclasses) {
        atags = gclass.getElementsByTagName('a');
        alert(atags);
        tag1 = atags[0];
        htmlattribute1 =  tag1.getAttribute('html');
        if (htmlattribute1 == uri) {
            sitefound = htmlattribute1;
            return sitefound;
        }

    }
    return null;
}
```

parsedHTML is a XULElement
gclasses is an HTMLCollection

if there are many divs of class G in the Google Directory search results, why are the g classes empty?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var tempDiv = document.createElement('div');
```

If you're in an XUL environment, that's not creating an HTML element node: it'll be an XUL element. Since the `innerHTML` property is exclusive to `HTMLElement` and not other XML `Element`​s, setting `innerHTML` on tempDiv will do nothing (other than adding a custom property containing the HTML string). Consequently there are no elements with class ‘g’ inside tempDiv... there are no elements at all inside it.

If you have a plain HTML document loaded in the browser, you could try using `content.document.createElement` to get an HTML wrapper element on which `innerHTML` will be available. This still isn't a brilliant way to parse a whole page of HTML because the document in question might have `<head>` content you can't put in a div, and HTTP headers that you'll be throwing away. Probably better to load the target file into an HTMLDocument object of its own. A good way to do that would be using an `iframe`. See [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/HTML_to_DOM) for examples of both these approaches.

```
tempDiv.innerHTML = myHTML.replace(/<script(.|\s)*?\/script>/g, '');
```

It's seven shades of not-a-good-idea to process HTML with regex; this could go wrong in many ways when Google slightly change their page markup. Let the browser do the job of parsing instead. Setting `innerHTML` does not cause script elements to be executed straight away (futher DOM manipulations can though); you can pick out the unwanted script elements later, if you need to. With the XUL iframe approach you can simply disable JavaScript on the iframe.

```
for (var gclass in gclasses) {
```

The `for...in` loop is for use against Objects used as mappings. It should *not* be used for iterating a sequence (such as Array, NodeList or in this case HTMLCollection) as it doesn't do what you might expect. For iterating sequences, stick to the standard C-style `for (var i= 0; i<sequence.length; i++)` loop.

You could also do with adding `var` declarations for all your other local variables.